# Could not write to output file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\''\''\''\''' -- 'Access is denied. '

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I have an asp.net project which is running well in visual studio 2013 development server and in IIS local host. But when I upload the project in online hosting, the error showing

> CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8d0dec5c\beef09e6\App_Code.u8avtytx.dll' -- 'Access is denied. '

I tried many thing to resolve the issues like the below:
http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/local-iis-7-0-cs0016--could-not-write-to-output-file-microsoft-net-framework-v4-0-30319-temporary-asp-net-files

and

https://forums.asp.net/t/1353803.aspx?CS0016%20Could%20not%20write%20to%20output%20file

and many more but no result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give permission to those folders where write actions are being performed (i.e Upload, File open and edit). Check all options from the permission tab from the server.

Comment: Dear shahjahan, i am very new to server issues. I can not understand this "Check all options from the permission tab from the server".

Comment: Your directory where you've uploaded published files, there will be a couple of folders you need to give permission. rclick over the folders and select permission, you will be redirected to a permission page. There you will see four/five type permission on the left and on the right there will be check boxes. Select one from left and give all permission from right [But don't give write permission to the source code folders]. That's all. If you couldn't figure it out then R&D about Asp.Net Web Servers. Good Luck

Comment: i gave permission to Temporary asp.net files folder and to c:/windows/temp folder but still same error. here is the detailed complier output below:

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely about the rights of the user set on Application Pool. In my case, NETWORK SERVICE; I've added this user to the Administrators group and after an IIS Reset the error has gone.